# How come NPRuntime require xpt file?

Tags: mozilla, npapi, npruntime

I am trying to make sense of whatever I learned about  **NPRuntime**. [Here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/modules/plugin/sdk/samples/npruntime/npp_gate.cpp#144) is a example of **NPRuntime** plugin from from **mozilla-central** of **NPRuntime** plugin, which mentions following lines

```
// ==============================
145 // ! Scriptability related code !
146 // ==============================
147 //
148 // here the plugin is asked by Mozilla to tell if it is scriptable
149 // we should return a valid interface id and a pointer to 
150 // nsScriptablePeer interface which we should have implemented
151 // and which should be defined in the corressponding *.xpt file
152 // in the bin/components folder
```

Now AFAIK **NPRuntime** desn't require to copy **xpt** file, **xpt** file is specific to **XPCOM** and **NPRuntime** does not use **XPCOM**. So what does above statement mean ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That comment lies, both about xpt and the nsScriptablePeer, as you can see from the actual code. Please file a bug in Core:Plugins about this and mention it in a comment (bonus points for the patch!)

Comment: Thanks .. Reported the bug : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546629 ... couldn't create the patch though  :)